# How to load google maps javascript api in Aurelia javascript application?

Tags: node.js, google-maps-api-3, aurelia, jspm, systemjs

I found npm module google-maps-api and installed it (npm install google-maps-api) but I can't figure out how to import it with systemjs/jspm (jspm cannot find this module). Here's the configuration from my config.js:

```
"paths": {
"*": "app/dist/*.js",
"github:*": "app/jspm_packages/github/*.js",
"npm:*": "app/jspm_packages/npm/*.js" }
```

So, when I try do something like this:

```
import {mapsapi} from 'google-maps-api';
```

I get the following error in browser console:

> GET https://localhost:44308/app/dist/google-maps-api.js 404 (Not Found)

Looking at the filesystem I see that npm installed the module under app/node_modules/google-maps-api so how do I reference it in the import clause from Aurelia module?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I found a solution and answering my own question here:

I finally figured how to install it with jspm, so you just need to give a hint to jspm to install it from npm like so:

> jspm install npm:google-maps-api

After jspm completes installation, import (no {} syntax) works fine:

```
import mapsapi from 'google-maps-api';
```

then I inject it in constructor and instantiate geocoder api:

```
@inject(mapsapi('InsertYourGMAPIKeyHere'))
export class MyClass {         
    constructor(mapsapi) {
        let that = this;
        let maps = mapsapi.then( function(maps) {
            that.maps = maps;
            that.geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
        });
...
}
```

In order to create map on a div I use EventAggregator to subscribe for router:navigation:complete event and use setTimeout to schedule map creation:

```
        this.eventAggregator.subscribe('router:navigation:complete', function (e) {
        if (e.instruction.fragment === "/yourRouteHere") { 
            setTimeout(function() {
                that.map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-div'),
                {
                    center: new google.maps.LatLng(38.8977, -77.0366),
                    zoom: 15
                });
            }, 200);
        }
    });
```

Comment: tried activate()? (or attached() if it's a custom element)

Comment: Assuming the same activation event model as Durandal (plausible but not guaranteed) you want the compositionComplete event. I take a difference approach: for something like maps which generally commandeer the whole window I just put a general purpose container in the shell markup styled to fully occupy the window but with a low z-index. That way the div is available at all stages in view lifecycle, and you get the same origin and coordinate system but your views float over. I find that having each toolwindow managed by a viewmodel produces lovely tidy code.

Comment: does the google-maps-api library support loading libraries? like the places library? That's what I'm trying to figure out...

Comment: Yes, you can load the places library. I just wrote a small tutorial at http://blog.thecoderecipe.com/articles/aurelia/places/2015/12/06/aurelia-places-autocomplete.html and a sample at http://github.com/TheCodeRecipe/sample-aurelia-places-autocomplete. I hope that helps!

Comment: Note that if you are using TypeScript, as for TypeScript 1.7, you need use "import * as mapsapi from 'google-maps-api';" Also, the library supports Google Maps for business and other parameters. See https://www.npmjs.com/package/google-maps-api for detail.

Answer (score 6):

Here's a complete view-model example that uses `attached()` to link to your view.

```
import {inject} from 'aurelia-framework';
import mapsapi from 'google-maps-api';

@inject(mapsapi('your map key here'))

export class MapClass {

    constructor(mapsAPI) {

        this.mapLoadingPromise = mapsAPI.then(maps => {
            this.maps = maps;
        });
    }

    attached() {

        this.mapLoadingPromise.then(() => {

            var startCoords = {
                lat:  0,
                long: 0
            };

            new this.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-div'), {
                center: new this.maps.LatLng(startCoords.lat, startCoords.long),
                zoom:   15
            });
        });
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

For everyone using Typescript and getting "Cannot find module 'google-maps-api'" error, 
you need to add typings to the solution. Something like this works

```
declare module 'google-maps-api' {

    function mapsapi(apikey: string, libraries?, onComplete?);

    namespace mapsapi {
    }

    export = mapsapi;
}
```

and then import it like this

```
import * as mapsapi from 'google-maps-api';
```